# Database connector's Insert operation for inserting Datetime type issue

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-connector

I am using Mulesoft database connector insert operation, I need to insert currentTime into mssql column defined as  datetime type.

When I use var currentTime = now() as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}
it fails with error the conversion from unknown to timestamp is unsupported
When I use var currentTime = now() as String { format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" }, it works. I thought now() as DateTime should work but not now() as String.
could anyone give me some hints?

thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean you are using Mule runtime, and your application is using the Database connector's Insert operation? Please add to your question the operation in XML text format.

Comment: You found how to make it work, so what is your question or issue?

Comment: I guess the String is overloaded with the date format but DateTime not.

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: For Mule configurations, flows and operations you can use the XML text representation.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify why your solution works, DataWeave doesn't support SQL DateTime types so trying to use a DataWeave DateTime directly in an SQL operation usually fails. Depending of the specific database you are using it may auto convert a String with the right format into an SQL DateTime -which is what is happening in your solution- or the database may require some SQL expression to convert the String. For example in the case of Oracle using `TO_DATE()` or a similar function.

Comment: chatGPT is banned in Stackoverlow. And that answer doesn't make sense.